# Loop within predefined window in Pandas

Tags: pandas, for-loop, data-analysis

I have a dataset which is divided in windows:

```
data_new_pd = (
  data_pd
  .filter(col('x') > 1)  
  .filter(col('x') < 21)  
  .withColumn('row', row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('a', 'b').orderBy('timestamp')))
  .filter(col('row') == 1)
  .toPandas()
)
```

The partioned windows do not have the same length.

Now I wanted to add the following loop over the defined Window you see above

```
# Make a new column
data_new_pd["temp_filter"] = 0

# Keep the latest value of the temperature column when column 'overshoot' = 0
last_temperature = None
for index, row in data_new_pd.iterrows():
    if row["overshoot"] == 0:
        last_temperature = row["temperature"]
    data_new_pd.at[index, "temp_filter"] = last_temperature
```

I tried to add a new column with some conditions, but it did not give me the correct result.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `data_new_pd` with the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want the last temperature for which overshoot is null. I would use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html), optionally with [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
data_new_pd['temp_filter'] = (data_new_pd['temperature']
                              .where(data_new_pd['overshoot'].eq(0))
                              .ffill()
                              .fillna(0)
                             )
```

If you want to `ffill` per group, use:

```
data_new_pd['temp_filter'] = (data_new_pd['temperature']
                              .where(data_new_pd['overshoot'].eq(0))
                              .groupby([data_new_pd['a'], data_new_pd['b']])
                              .ffill()
                              .fillna(0)
                             )
```

Example:

```
   overshoot  temperature  temp_filter
0          0          440        440.0
1          0          441        441.0
2          0          442        442.0
3          1          443        442.0
4          1          444        442.0
5          1          445        442.0
6          1          446        442.0
7          0          447        447.0
8          0          448        448.0
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway. However, using this code, for every 1 in column 'overshoot' I get a 0 in the column temp_filter. Let me give an example:

If column overshoot = 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 0 
Column temp filter should become: 440, 530, 470, 470, 470, 470, 470, 510, 520.

So when overshoot becomes 1, temp_filter should be equal to the last time column overshoot was 0. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Worstenbrood96 not really, please edit your question and add a DataFrame constructor to provide a clear **reproducible** input/output